# Error when rying to call sqoop 1.4.6 through Java API, Sqoop.runTool, using HCATALOG

Tags: sqoop

When we call Sqoop.runTool to import from an Oracle Database. once time the Map And Reduce is launcher it's unable to find the HCATALOG classes:

> 2017-09-18 09:04:47,546 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:519)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:499)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1598)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:499)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:285)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1556)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1553)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2214)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:222)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:515)
>       ... 11 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2120)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2212)
>       ... 13 more

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is about specific and answerable programming related questions. Please can you review these and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the solution setting in the configuration object before call to Sqoop.runTool(s[], conf) the hcatalog jars in a hdfs path

```
        conf.set("tmpjars", "/lib/hive-exec-1.2.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar,/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar,/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar...");
```